# Kate editor: how to jump to modified lines?

Tags: kate

Say I'm editing a long document and I have made a number of changes. I want to be able to jump to each changed line. Is there a way to do this?

I know about line modification indicators and I have those turned on. But for a long document, it is not easy to find those line modification indicators. I want a way to jump directly there.

I turned on scroll bar marks. I'm not sure what that feature is supposed to do, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: I'm still looking for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am the Kate developer who implemented the [line modification system](http://kate-editor.org/2011/09/06/line-modification-system/). As of now, the feature to jump to modified lines is not implemented. If you would like to see this feature in future Kate releases, please [vote for the wish](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=310738).

As for the second part of your question: The scroll bar marks are for bookmarks (Ctrl+B) and Search & Replace highlights. This is unrelated to the line modification system.

As a side note: Since KDE 4.10, Kate has a mini map that can be enabled instead of the scroll bar through `Settings` > `Configure Kate` > `Appearance` > `Borders` > `[x] Show Scrollbar Minimap`. This minimap will also show the line modification markers, so that you can easily jump to the desired location with the mouse.

Comment: Btw, how would you expect this to work: If you have several lines modified in a row, would you jump to each line, or rather to the start, middle, end of this block?

Comment: Thanks for your interest in this. I believe Kate's existing line modification colors impact the decision about this feature. I think jumping to the beginning of a block of modified lines when jumping forward is adequate. (Maybe jump to end when jumping backwards.) With Kate's existing line modification visual clue, once we jump to the modified lines, we can see if there is a block of adjacent lines. (Without visual clues I could see the need to jump to each and every modified line even if they are adjacent.)

Comment: BTW, does the Kate team plan to implement scroll bar marks for line modification in the future?  I would vote for that feature too. And I have to add that I think your implementation of the [line modification system](http://kate-editor.org/2011/09/06/line-modification-system/) is really awesome! It is **very** useful for me and it will become even more useful with the ability to jump to next/previous changes.

Comment: Ok, I'll take a note and see whether I'll get around to implement this. With respect to showing this indicators in the scrollbar: The line modification indicators are shown iff you use the minimap.

Comment: Thanks for continuing to pursue this! (I'll make a donation if you get this implemented within the next month or so.)

Comment: Added in KDE 4.13, see https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=310738 - if you want, you can build it already now by following http://kate-editor.org/get-it/

Comment: @dhaumann-thanks! that's a great tutorial for building Kate from source. I'm going to give that a try.